# SSMS - Removing Ampersand & Characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

If I run the following, the & value gets replaced with and

```
select 
     replace('Difference_between_desired_date_&_generic_window float', '&', 'and') as [col_1]
```

If I run the following, the & does not get replaced, even though the same value from my first example is in the column (I copied it from the column for my first example actually):

```
select 
     replace([column_with_my_value], '&', 'and') as [col_2]
```

Why is this?

Comment: Not sure why we are voting to close this...

Comment: My guess is missing a [mre] - can you create a dbfiddle?

Comment: I mean, it's a pretty simple example no? I figured it out, but you basically just need to do a select into for the 2nd part to reproduce the entire example, am I wrong?

Comment: What is the column collation?

Comment: @LunchBox um, no, see my fiddle below your answer - thats why a [mre] is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to escape the & character.

Replace this:

```
select 
     replace([column_with_my_value], '&', 'and') as [col_2]
```

With this:

```
select 
     replace([column_with_my_value], '\&', 'and') as [col_2]
```

and it works fine, though I'm not sure why it works with 1 and not the other.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, there is clearly more happening than you have manged to explain see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=81e07ae519cac87c0fb8b8f7b31c4a0c) where the expected code works and your fix doesn't.

Comment: There is nothing more happening. I have a bunch of values (col_1) that are in a column (col_2) and the bottom replace function worked. I'm not sure why, but I guess it's because there was some escaping that needed to be done?